# Basic precalculus, Interval notation check

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**A.** $(x + 8)^2(x + 5) > 0$

My answer: $(-\infty,-8)\cup(-5,\infty)$

**B.** $5 < 2x − 5 < 9$

My answer: $(-\infty,5)\cap(7,\infty)$

**C.** $x(4 − 5x) \le 0$

My answer: $(-\infty,0]\cup[\frac45,\infty)$

**D.** $(x + 8)^2(x + 5) > 0$

My answer: $(-\infty,-8)\cup(-5,\infty)$

Please explain if these are correct or incorrect.

Thank You

Comment: I edited your post using $\LaTeX$. Please make sure that I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: A:choose a number in $(-\infty,-8)$, substitute in $(x + 8)^2(x + 5) $ does it become $> 0$?

Comment: Is A and B correct as well?

Comment: x>-5
so would it be: (-5,∞) ?

Comment: @Jimmie, If you are answering question (A), then Yes, your answer is correct :)

Comment: Yes, and for B that's just (5,7) since it's 5<x<7?

Comment: @Jimmie, superb!, again correct :)

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

> > A. $(x+8)^2 (x+5)>0$
>
> My answer: $(−∞,−8)∪(−5,∞)$

Incorrect.

Notice: $(-9+8)^2(-9+5) = -4$

In general, the squared factor will always be positive for real values, so you only need to determine when the other factor is negative for the product to be negative.

> > B. $5<2x−5<9 $
>
> My answer: $(−∞,5)∩(7,∞)$

Hint: That intersection is empty.  Also incorrect as $5< 2\times 6 - 5 < 9$

You want $x$ such that $2x-5 > 5$, and $2x-5 < 9$ ...

> > C. $x(4−5x)≤0$
>
> My answer: $(−∞,0]∪[\tfrac 4 5 ,∞)$

$\checkmark$ Correct.

> > D. $(x+8)^2 (x+5)>0 $
>
> My answer: $(−∞,−8)∪(−5,∞)$

Again, a squared factor is always positive for real values, so you need to identify when $x+5$ is positive.